# Choose which item to pop from list

Tags: python, oop, random, indexing

building a "little" card game.

Lets look at my problem.

I can draw cards from the deck and put the last drawn card back on top.

But I want to decide which card should placed back on top!

```
import random
```

lets assume we have some "cards"

`Cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

a `Deck Class`

```
class Deck():                             # Deck class definition for deck of cards
    

    def __init__(self, Cards):                   # Creating an empty list of cards. Constructor.
        self.cards = Cards
      
    
    def deal(self, i=-1):                  # Method to deal the top most card of the deck
        return self.cards.pop(i)

    
    def shuffle(self):                     # Method to shuffle the deck of cards
        random.shuffle(self.cards)         # Shuffling the card deck
```

and a `Player Class`

```
class Player():
    
    def __init__(self):


        # creat deck for each player
        self.deck = Deck([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) 
        # shuffle the deck before the hand is drawn
        self.deck.shuffle()
        
        # draw the starthand
        self.hand = []
        for i in range(3):
            card = self.deck.deal()
            self.hand.append(card)
        
                        

    def draw(self):
        card = self.deck.deal()
        return self.hand.append(card)

    
    def on_top(self, i=-1):
        card = self.hand.pop(i)
        return self.deck.cards.append(card)
```

When the Player is created with

`player_1 = Player()`

the list of cards is shuffled and 3 cards are drawn

lets check the hand

`player_1.hand`

`[1, 4, 5]`

when a card is drawn

`player_1.draw()`

and hand checked again

`player_1.hand`

`[1, 4, 5, 3]`

the next item from list is drawn.

Ok lets place the item back on top

`player_1.on_top()`

`player_1.hand`

`[1, 4, 5]`

---

Ok perfect.
But how can I choose the card to put back on top of the deck by my self?

And the very next question would be:

How to search for a specific Item in the list and choose to draw?

You should imagine that the numbers are replaced by a front of a card.

Thanks already for helping me!

Comment: In the general case, this is probably not quite the correct object model. Players don't typically have a deck of cards. They have a hand. A game involves 1+ players, each with a hand. The deck exists and is modeled independently of the players.

Comment: In this game every player has it's own deck of cards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I can help you enough, still struggling to learn Python OOP, but I will give it a try *with my noob mindset*

I think with the way you defined your `on_top()` you could simply give and index as argument `i`

```py
>>> player1.on_top(1)    # choosing 4 (with index 1) to be put on top
>>> player1.hand
[1, 5]
```

- Now I will assume that what you meant with

> How to search for a specific Item in the list and choose to draw?

means that you want to `on_top()` a card from your hand (without knowing which index it has)

```py
>>> player_1.on_top(player_1.hand.index(5))    # let's say you put away the card 5
>>> player_1.hand
[1]
```

- If instead you want to `draw()` it from the deck, had to change your function a bit

```py
...
def draw(self, i=-1):    # adding `i` argument here 
        card = self.deck.deal(i)    # and here
        return self.hand.append(card)
...
```

so that this could work out

```py
>>> player_1.draw(player_1.deck.cards.index(5))
>>> player_1.hand
[1, 5]
```

I guess this way of writing would be hard to read

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
How could I miss the first... stupid me..
The Second works also now!!
I'll post the answer under this comment

Comment: Take in consideration that you make it all random. So the hands changes every time you run the code. What is the output you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok not that hard tbh.

Put a specific card back on top ist easy with the `i` index like in the answer before

`player1.on_top(1)`

And for searching the deck I added a new function to the `Player Class`

```
    def search(self, i=-1):    # adding `i` argument here 
        card = self.deck.deal(i)    # and here
        return self.hand.append(card)
```

with this you can easy access the cards by it's index

`player_1.search(3) # search for the 3rd card in deck and put it into hand`

Thanks a lot for your help!